Get post's author data in a shortcode within the WordPress loop
I am building a block theme for Wordpress.
I wrote a shortcode function that is supposed to output the message "By [author's display name with author's link]".
More specifically, I am trying to use it in the search result loop (main loop for the search result template).
function auteur_par(){
    $auteur = get_the_author();
    $auteur_nom = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $auteur);
    $auteur_url = get_the_author_meta('user_url', $auteur);
    return '<p>Par <a href="' . $auteur_url . '" target="_self" class="wp-block-post-author-name__link">' . $auteur_nom . '</a></p>';
}
add_shortcode('auteur_par', 'auteur_par');

I also tried using get_the_author_meta directly:
function auteur_par(){
    $auteur_nom = get_the_author_meta('display_name');
    $auteur_url = get_the_author_meta('user_url');
    return '<p>Par <a href="' . $auteur_url . '" target="_self" class="wp-block-post-author-name__link">' . $auteur_nom . '</a></p>';
}
add_shortcode('auteur_par', 'auteur_par');

Both don't work work when I use it as a shortcode within the "Modèle de publication" block (I can't find what the english name is for this block, it's the block under the query loop block in the outline). On the page, the paragraph is there, but the variables are empty.
I made a similar function using get_the_modified_date() and that one works perfectly. I don't understand why it works for the modification date but not for the author.
I tried the solutions referenced in this post and this post but it doesn't work.

You need to get the Author ID like in your 2nd linked thread, then from that author ID you will be able to get the WP_User related object and get any user data from the author.
Try the following:
function auteur_par_shortcode(){
    $author_id   = get_post_field ('post_author', get_the_ID()); // Get author ID
    $author_user = new WP_User($author_id); // Get Author WP_User object
   
    return sprintf('<p>%s <a href="%s" target="_self" class="wp-block-post-author-name__link">%s</a></p>',
        esc_html__('Par'), $author_user->user_url, $author_user->display_name);
}
add_shortcode('auteur_par', 'auteur_par_shortcode');



It should work now.
Usage: [auteur_par]

It works thanks. That said I don't understand why it is so complicated to just get an author's display name even though it is so simple for other fields like publication dates.

I take that back. It doesn't work. It always displays the author of the first post in the loop for ALL posts in the loop. I don't get it.

So the problem may be related to the WordPress loop itself, that is not built in the correct way.

I am using the main loop in my search result template, I put the shortcode within the Modèle de publication block. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. If I really can't solve this I will do what I want in JS but I'd rather do this in the PHP backend.

You can use the below shortcode to retrieve and display the author data within the WordPress loop. Add the following code to your theme’s functions.php file:

function author_post_get_data_shortcode_sp() {    
    global $post;   
    if ( ! $post ) {
        return ''; 
    }    
    $author_id = $post->post_author;
    
    $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id );
    $author_url = get_author_posts_url( $author_id );
    $author_description = get_the_author_meta( 'description', $author_id );
    $author_avatar = get_avatar( $author_id, 64 ); 
    
    $html = '<div class="author-info">';
    $html .= '<h4>Author Name: <a href="' . esc_url( $author_url ) . '">' . esc_html( $author_name ) . '</a></h4>';   
    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('author_post_get_data','author_post_get_data_shortcode_sp');


It doesn't work either. Same problem as the other post : it always display the author of the first post in the loop.
